# What am I doing wrong converting Razor to ASPX?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am doing a simple (I think) tutorial for MVC.  The only issue is the tutorial uses `Razor` and I need to use `ASPX`.  Job I'm looking at uses it.

I have spent hours looking over the internet for possibilities but I am still getting this error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to 
>   service this request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>   Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)   Source Error:
>
> Line 12:
>   Line 13:     
>   Line 14:     Restaurant: <%: Model.Name %>
>   Line 15:     Rating:  <%: Model.Rating %>
>   Line 16:

**The controller code is:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using EdeToFood.Models;

namespace EdeToFood.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            var model = new RestaurantReview()
            {
                Name = "Tersiguil's",
                Rating = 9
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Location = "Maryland, USA";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**The ASPX is:**

```
%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewBag.Message %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>

    <div >
    Restaurant:  <%: Model.Name %>
    Rating:  <%: Model.Rating %>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You are missing `<` at the beginning of the aspx page, but it's probably a copy paste issue. see my answer below.

Comment: I only read the question title, but it sounds like everything.

Comment: Where can we find the tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use strongly typed views You have to define the `View Model` of the page in this line:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TheViewModel>" %>
```

So in your case it should be;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RestaurantReview>" %>
```

If you don't specify anything as you did, The `ViewModel` will be object, and as you well know, it doesn't have `Name` or `Rating` properties.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't want the colon as part of the script delimiter:

```
<h2><% ViewBag.Message %></h2>
```

You can also use a different syntax with the equals sign as a shortcut for `Response.Write()`, e.g.

```
<%=DateTime.Now %>
```

[Source](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs)

Comment: the colon specifies that the output of the script delimiter should be HTML Encoded